# UWP on RPi - Trying to Provision to Azure - How to get X.509 certificate

Tags: azure, uwp, raspberry-pi, provisioning, windows-10-iot-core

I'm working with a RPi/UWP program (works well) that is signed with out X.509 certificate.
I have no problems connecting to Azure IoT hub if I manually provision the connection, but as we intend to ship these by the 100s, if not thousands, obviously that won't work.

I've looked at the code examples of using the provisioning service, but all of them are in the emulation.
Looking at the code, you have to load your X.509 certificate

```
        certificateCollection.Import(s_certificateFileName, certificatePassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.UserKeySet);
```

This is where I get lost - Where on the RPi IS the certificate to load?
Basically, I *THINK* I understand how to do this in a plain Win10 app, but when you get to UWP on the RPi (a 3B, as the 3B+ is not supported - probably have to switch to Core) .  Anyone have some sample code, or can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

This [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/cryptography) provides an overview of the cryptography features available to UWP apps.
You can generate the certificate file and then copy or import it to the device. If you copy the certificate file to device, you need to add capabilities for accessing the file to your UWP app. Please refer to this [topic](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f61a4180-61d5-4a01-84b6-6e9554b1b38e/file-access-on-windows-iot-core) in MSDN forum. Following code can be used to import the pfx certificate into your device and then load it from cert store.

**Import**:

```
StorageFolder certificatesFolder = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("Certificates");

StorageFile certificateFile = await certificatesFolder.GetFileAsync("ClientCertificate .pfx  ");

IBuffer certificateBuffer = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(certificateFile);

string encodedCertificate = Windows.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(certificateBuffer);

await CertificateEnrollmentManager.ImportPfxDataAsync(encodedCertificate, "password", ExportOption.NotExportable, KeyProtectionLevel.NoConsent, InstallOptions.None, "certificateOne");
```

**Load:**

```
CertificateQuery certQuery = new CertificateQuery();
 certQuery.FriendlyName = "certificateOne";
 IReadOnlyList<Certificate> certificates = await CertificateStores.FindAllAsync(certQuery);
```

Comment: The question was where to find it to load it, but I think I see what you were doing